# Recover photos from the Internal Memory on the Instax Mini Evo

Tags: fujifilm-instax

I was using the internal memory on the Instax mini Evo to hold my photos before getting a micro SD card for it. Once I out in the Sd card, the photos in the internal memory were lost. Is there any way to recover these? I tried just taking out the Sd since I hadn't formatted it yet, and they were still gone.

Comment: Did you try to connect the camera to a computer via USB?

Answer (score 0):

Hii it happen the same to me. just take out the SD card you will see still your photos you took before of SD card. so probably it doesn't show up because you already took photos with SD card on it!! you I will recommend you just to make a copy on your computer and then put again the SD card and the delete the photos. automatically it will show up the pictures of the internal storage, you just have to make a copy to the SD. I don't know if you get me lol. it's to late to help you but minutes ago happen the same to me!!